# How to build Broadleaf eCommerce Demo site project set up in spring tool suite?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I just download the broad leaf E-commerce Demo Site project(https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite) from GitHub and import it to STS but unable to run this project .Can any one help me out I am new to this framework.

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/web] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)I just run the admin module

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only error you are facing then this is because of jdbc/web resource is not defined in server.xml/context.xml file under  `<GlobalNamingResources>` tag as shown below

```
   <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer" logAbandoned="true" maxActive="10" maxIdle="5" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" minIdle="1" name="jdbc/web" password="root" removeAbandoned="false" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false" testWhileIdle="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" username="root" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

I am posting this as an answer for readability perspective, you may have other problems in your application too. Let me know if this solves your problem or not. Also check whether you have defined the same in the applicationContext-datasource.xml or not, you can also find an example of how to define them in context.xml in the `lib/tomcat-server-config/context.xml` file. I have defined it in my tomcat's server.xml file.